# Weird JSON Javascript problem in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to get my JSON from my controller to my view. In my controller I am doing:

```
@nodes = Node.all
@json = @nodes.as_json(:only => [:ID, :Lat, :Lon])
```

In my view I have tried:

```
1) var stuff = <%= @json %>
2) var stuff = <%= @json.to_json %>
3) var stuff = <%= @json.to_json.to_json %>
```

and all of those give me an error. I usually get an `"Unexpected Syntax Error &" or "Unexpected Syntax Error {"`

I have also tried using jquery and using respond_to within the controller, but that doesn't seem to work either.

My thoughts are that getting json to the view shouldn't be a big issue and shouldn't require jQuery, and currently, my page source looks like:

```
var stuff = [{&quot;node&quot;:{&quot;ID&quot;:1301499692582,&quot;Lat&quot;:42.3605063113369,&quot;Lon&quot;:-71.0870862191138}},{&quot;node&quot;:{&quot;ID&quot;:1301499691515,&quot;Lat&quot;:42.3605147089149,&quot;Lon&quot;:-71.0870533282532}},{&quot;node&quot;:{&quot;ID&quot;:1301431075499,&quot;Lat&quot;:42.3605456103,&quot;Lon&quot;:-71.0875239075536}} etc
```

I dont understand the &quot symbols (maybe thats where the syntax error is coming from) but when I do render :`json => @nodes.to_json`, the page renders a normal json that is valid:

```
[{"node":{"ID":1301499692582,"Lat":42.3605063113369,"Lon":-71.0870862191138}},{"node":{"ID":1301499691515,"Lat":42.3605147089149,"Lon":-71.0870533282532}},{"node":{"ID":1301431075499,"Lat":42.3605456103,"Lon":-71.0875239075536}}
```

Note: I've also tried doing `var stuff = '<%= @json.to_json` %> but when I do `var json = JSON.parse(stuff)`, it gives me an illegal token error.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is Rails html-encoding your string as is default in Rails 3.

You need to mark your JSON as `html_safe`:

```
var stuff = <%= @json.to_s.html_safe %>
```

Note that `.to_s` is needed because `as_json` gives Hash instead of string. You could do this instead:

```
# in controller
@json = @nodes.to_json(:only => [:ID, :Lat, :Lon]) 

#and in view
var stuff = <%= @json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now it shows up in the source as its supposed to be. If you don't mind, could you give me an example as to how I can access each object in the JSON? I would truly appreciate it!

Comment: Nice! Sorry, that I coudn't respond sooner.

Comment: Isn't this unsafe if `@json` contains untrusted data? Or does `to_json` escape dangerous stuff properly?

Comment: `to_json` should output valid JSON and that means that any Rails variable would be either `integer` or a properly quoted `string` (or an array /object made of them), no automatically executable JS code. Theorethically this means that code injection won't be possible (until you start blindly `eval`-ing the JSON).

Comment: I had problems with to_s (using Rails 4). <%= @json.to_json.html_safe %> worked though

Comment: Thank you! As @Sid said (using Rails 4/5), you'll need to use .to_json.html_safe ... to_s uses  key => value instead of key:value

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put quotes around it, then you can ask jquery to parse the string into JSON.