# Rails render JSON using <%= not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm currently trying to return multiple JSON objects in one of my controllers as such.

```
  @chromosomes = @organism.chromosomes.to_json
  @file_data = current_user.files.to_json
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
```

However, on the front end when I do:

```
 <%= @chromosomes %>
```

or

```
  <%= @file_data %>
```

I don't get a JSON object, instead I get the data as a string with things such as &quote, etc. I've tried parsing the string such as

```
console.log($.parseJSON("<%= @chromosomes %>"));
```

but it still isn't working. Is this is because the request being sent back is html?

Thanks!

Comment: You've edited the question, but the answer is still the same, see below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look something like this,

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @organism.chromosomes) }
    format.json { render :json => @organism.chromosomes) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
render :json => @organism.chromosomes
```

By looked at you edit, I think what you want is below:

```
console.log($.parseJSON("<%= raw @chromosomes %>"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I'm still not getting a json object on the front end when I output it. I've updated the question with further details. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up lying in the fact that Rails encoded the json data as a string, which is the default. To fix the issue I used

```
 <%= @chromosomes.html_safe %>
```

on the front end. Further info about this can be found here:

[Weird JSON Javascript problem in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970419/weird-json-javascript-problem-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, for Rails 2,

```
console.log($.parseJSON(<%= @chromosomes.dump %>));
```

for Rails 3,

```
console.log($.parseJSON(<%= @chromosomes.dump.html_safe %>));
```

String#dump escapes the characters and makes parseJSON() work. Notice that no quotation marks needed.