# How to access JSON from a rails @variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

In rails I'm calling an API that returns JSON:

```
{"observations":{"realtime_start":"2012-12-27","realtime_end":"2012-12-27","observation_start":"1776-07-04","observation_end":"9999-12-31","units":"pca","output_type":"1","file_type":"xml","order_by":"observation_date","sort_order":"asc","count":"263","offset":"0","limit":"100000","observation":[{"realtime_start":"2012-12-27","realtime_end":"2012-12-27","date":"1947-01-01","value":"."},{"realtime_start":"2012-12-27","realtime_end":"2012-12-27","date":"1947-04-01","value":"-0.60853"}
```

In a controller I'm passing the JSON into an instance variable:

```
# Send the http request
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)


# captures the http response
test = response.body

#converts the http response hash from xml to json
show_info = Hash.from_xml(test).to_json
@it = show_info
```

Finally I render out the instance variable in a view:

```
<script>
x = "<%= @it %>"
</script>
```

If I type x enter in the console, the json pops up formatted a bit differently which may be my problem..

```
 "{&quot;observations&quot;:{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;observation_start&quot;:&quot;1776-07-04&quot;,&quot;observation_end&quot;:&quot;9999-12-31&quot;,&quot;units&quot;:&quot;pca&quot;,&quot;output_type&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;file_type&quot;:&quot;xml&quot;,&quot;order_by&quot;:&quot;observation_date&quot;,&quot;sort_order&quot;:&quot;asc&quot;,&quot;count&quot;:&quot;263&quot;,&quot;offset&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;limit&quot;:&quot;100000&quot;,&quot;observation&quot;:[{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2010-10-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;2.39307&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2011-01-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;0.07892&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2011-04-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;2.47721&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2011-07-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;1.27864&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2011-10-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;4.09234&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2012-01-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;1.96053&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2012-04-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;1.25266&quot;},{&quot;realtime_start&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;realtime_end&quot;:&quot;2012-12-27&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2012-07-01&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;3.10599&quot;}]}}"
```

My question is how do I access one of the key value pairs? Do I need to parse it in javascript? Is there a way to do this through dot notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely remember doing something like this before.  The problem was that I was getting a json string from a web service and then calling .to_json on it.

Try changing this:

```
Hash.from_xml(test).to_json
```

to this:

```
Hash.from_xml(test)
```

If that doesn't work, I think that this other post should help you format your json correctly: 
[Weird JSON Javascript problem in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970419/weird-json-javascript-problem-in-rails)

Comment: Changing the code in the template to var it = <%= @it.to_s.html_safe %> did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JSON in JavaScript is just a regular object, nothing more. So you just need to pass it without quotes, like this:

```
<script>
x = <%= @it %>;
</script>
```

After that in javascript your `x` will be just an object, and you will be able to access any info within it

Comment: I appreciate you looking at this, however, if I don't use quotes I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &"?

Comment: That means your JSON is with errors. Post it here so we would be able to understand where is the problem.

Comment: I edited the post to include the value of the javascript variable that is displayed in the console that is holding the json. Thanks again.